# Rewrite url in htaccess and php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file having the following code in my project

```
Options All -Indexes
errorDocument 400 http://dev.mistercabin.com/error.php
errorDocument 401 http://dev.mistercabin.com/error.php
errorDocument 403 http://dev.mistercabin.com/error.php
errorDocument 404 http://dev.mistercabin.com/error.php
errorDocument 500 http://dev.mistercabin.com/error.php
```

But I can not understand the meaning of those lines. please help.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: if the web server returns any of those headers, then serve the page listed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: As Dagon stated, if your server returns a response code of those listed above, the page `http://dev.mistercabin.com/error.php` will show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the webserver returns a http response with one of those codes they will return you to the page which you set,

so for example if your webserver responds with a 404 error because a requested page does not exist, you will be redirected to `http://dev.mistercabin.com/error.php`

Comment: Youre welcome :) make sure to mark an awnser in order to help future visitors.